# I am getting this gem install error for kgio gem when i do a bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, unicorn

I added unicorn to my Gemfile and after that when i do a bundle install I get this error

```
    em::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
/Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:686:in `macro_defined?'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:822:in `block in have_macro'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/adim86/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:821:in `have_macro'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adim86/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/kgio-2.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adim86/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/kgio-2.7.4/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing kgio (2.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.7.4'` succeeds before bundling
```

My gem file looks like this. I have tried adding unicorn to a production block but i still get the same error. I have also removed unicorn and i still get the same error also tried a bundle update to no avail:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'fb_graph'

gem 'json'
gem 'json_pure'

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'postmark'
gem 'postmark-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'watu_table_builder', :require => 'table_builder'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'differ'


gem 'whenever'
gem 'unicorn'
```

can anyone help?

Comment: intstall gcc, make and other necessary development tools, check  mkmf.log for more details

Comment: I have also installed gcc and all the xcode command line tools

Comment: have you found a solution? i'm having the same issue here.

Comment: having the same issue too. any solutions?

Comment: What I did was remove it (unicorn gem) do a bundle install, it worked well, put it back but put it in a group :production and then did a bundle install that said -- exclude production nd it seemed to work after that, not sure if that is a long term solution, i have not done a bundle install since then. ill keep you guys update

Comment: This might be useful for you. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1157

Comment: As @Adim pointed out, if `unicorn` is in the production group and this error occurs in development, then you can get around it with `bundle install --without production`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Xcode. Go to Xcode settings -> Downloads and make sure you have the "Command Line Tools" installed. Once I installed them, the `bundle install` ran just fine.

Comment: This was a life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Unicorn, is designed to take advantage of features found in Unix-like systems.

In other words, they won't work on Windows

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem recently. In my case it was because for some unknown reason the environment variable for CC (which is a shim to Apple's LLVM compiler) was not being set.
Typing:

```
$ export CC=cc
```

in the Terminal before doing the `bundle install` worked for me.

To make the change permanent you can add `export CC=cc` to your .bash_profile file.

If you do the latter, make sure you type:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

(or open a new Terminal window) before doing the `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

this might require newer patchlevel of ruby - like `p194` - install it:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p194
```

and try again with it.

You should always use the latest patchlevel available, RVM allows to do that with:

```
rvm get stable
rvm use 1.9.3 --install
```

Comment: this didn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: same for me UNTIL I upgraded ruby and rvm. rvm upgrade ruby-1.9.3-p194 ruby-1.9.3-p327

Answer (score -2):

I used `rvm use system` to install the gems. The price of living on the edge with ruby?